# Difference in fromOffset/untilOffset/offset.count to total records in the RDD partition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

My Spark-kakfa streaming logic looks like this...

When i look at the offsets and records, there is different in offset.count() of the partition and total number records actually printing when i use foreach loop.(on RDD partition).

Those counts were inconsistent with my logic.

Can someone guide me to correct my logic.???

```
JavaInputDStream<byte[]> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jsc, String.class, byte[].class,
        StringDecoder.class, DefaultDecoder.class, byte[].class, kafkaParams, topicMap,
        (Function<MessageAndMetadata<String, byte[]>, byte[]>) MessageAndMetadata::message);

directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
    rdd.foreachPartition(itr -> {
        Integer partnId = TaskContext.get().partitionId();

        ArrayList <byte[]> recordBatch = new ArrayList <byte[]>();

            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                byte[] record = itr.next();
                recordBatch.add(record);
            }

                OffsetRange[] offsets = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();
            //Partition 0 fromOffset 0 untilOffset 2 offset.count(): 2
            //Partition 1 fromOffset 0 untilOffset 3 offset.count(): 3
                for (OffsetRange offset : offsets) {

                    if (offset.partition() == partnId) {
                        recordBatch.forEach((rec) -> {
                        //Partition 0 fromOffset 0 untilOffset 2 offset.count(): 2 --> TOTAL RECORDS after LOOPING: 3
                        //Partition 1 fromOffset 0 untilOffset 3 offset.count(): 3 --> TOTAL RECORDS after LOOPING: 3
                            //Business Logic goes here.
                        }
                    } 
                } 

    });
});
```